# Import DS-5 plugin to an existing eclipse installation

Tags: eclipse-plugin, arm, licensing, ds-5

I have an existing eclipse installation to which I want to import DS-5 as a plugin. Is this supported for the paid versions, Professional and Ultimate edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DS-5 can be imported to Eclipse as a plugin. The page http://ds.arm.com/ds-5-community-edition/getting-started-update-site/ has details of how to install the plugin.

By default, you will get the Community edition's features. Features available across different editions can be seen at http://ds.arm.com/ds-5/compare-ds-5-editions/.

DS-5 plugin version contains full Streamline support. You can unlock this by buying either Professional or Ultimate edition license and setting it up. However, DS-5 plugin version does not support tools like FVP, ARM compiler and DS-5 Debugger.